# How to get the quantity of children inside the element using xpath query on the puppeter?

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I need to get the number of children inside an element with the page.$x(xpath) function in Puppeteer, mad I was not successful. In the browser console I can do it using $x().children.length. What would be the best way to do this in the puppeteer with node?

Comment: Just do it the same way inside of page.evaluate

Comment: It's a little different to get the result I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either element/JS handle API or pure Web API in `page.evaluate()`. These are both wways:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://example.org/');

    const [element] = await page.$x('//body/div');
    const children = await element.getProperty('children');
    const length1 = await (await children.getProperty('length')).jsonValue();
    console.log(length1); // 3

    const length2 = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.evaluate(
        '//body/div', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE
      ).singleNodeValue.children.length;
    });
    console.log(length2); // 3

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I managed to do something like your first resolution. But your way is shorter and more beautiful to read, thanks